# PowerShell to get .NET framework version that a site is running in IIS

Tags: .net, powershell, iis

Is there a way to use PowerShell to get the .NET framework that a web application is running on in IIS?

I have been able to use the following to get the website name and to see that the app pool is set up as "Clr4IntegratedAppPool," but I am not seeing a way to determine what version of .NET the site itself is running.

To clarify, I am trying to get the .NET version of the **site** itself, not the app pool. For example if Site1 is running version 4.6.2 under AppPool1 (which is set to 4.0) then I am trying to get to the 4.6.2.

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")

$sm = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager

foreach($site in $sm.Sites)
{
    $root = $site.Applications | where { $_.Path -eq "/" }
    Write-Output ("Site: " + $site.Name + " | Pool: " + $root.ApplicationPoolName )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
$myServer = "name of server"

$IIS = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($myServer)

foreach ($pool in $IIS.ApplicationPools)
{
    $pool.ManagedRuntimeVersion
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the framework version for the application pool, not the site itself if that makes sense. Do you know of a way to get the site's version? I will clarify on the original post!

Comment: Not sure I undestand. A site is related to an application pool which is running the worker processes for the applications? And since a process can only run a single .NET framework, an application needs to belong to the correct app pool? or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well I can have a website that is running .NET 4.6.2 for example, but the application pool would be set up as 4.0.

Comment: @KevinCress yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the bin folder of the site to iterate all dlls and identify the .NET framework version of those dlls.

```
Function Get-WebsiteDotNetVersion { 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$SiteName 
    ) 

    # get site root directory 
    $site = Get-WebSite -Name $SiteName 
    $binLocation = "$($site.physicalPath)\bin" 

    # get all dlls in bin folder 
    $dllFolder = Get-Item -Path $binLocation 
    $dlls = $dllFolder.GetFiles("*.dll") 

    # analyze dll .net version 
    $set = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String] 
    $dlls | ForEach-Object { 
        $set.Add([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("$binLocation\$($_.Name)").ImageRuntimeVersion) | Out-Null 
    } 

    # print all dll .NET version 
    $set 
}
```

For details please refer to [How to get .NET framework version of site running in IIS by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-get-NET-framework-4d7f7a45)

Answer (score 0):

An asp.net application looks at target framework attribute to find out which version of .Net to use

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

For more details refer this [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) .If it does not have that attribute set,It will use runtime 4.0

So to correctly figure out the site version, you need

- Get the Application pool runtime version.
- Go to the web.config file and check if targetFramework is present.

  - If targetFramework is present ,take that
  - If not,use the Application pool . Runtime

Hope this helps!