# How to determine .NET Framework requirements for internal IIS Sites/Application Pools?

Tags: .net, iis

Overflow Community,

As some of you may be aware, .NET Framework 3.5 (**not** SP1) is not supported by Microsoft and is therefore a big security risk. With this in mind, we are looking at removing 3.5 (and any below) frameworks from our servers.

We have a bunch of internal sites running on IIS v10.0.14393.0 and i need to be able to determine if any of these sites are have a .NET 3.5 dependency or not.

IIS is not my forte and whilst the following post is similar, it does not contain an accepted answer so im uncertain of any answers on there:
[PowerShell to get .NET framework version that a site is running in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307879/powershell-to-get-net-framework-version-that-a-site-is-running-in-iis)

Does anyone have an idea or able to offer guidance on how i can determine if any of our internal sites are depending on .NET 3.5 or below?

Many TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the application pool corresponding to each site, the AppPool .NET CLR version has a mapping relationship with the .NET Framework version.
You need to go to the "Application Pools" node in IIS Manager, select the application pool, and check the ".NET CLR Version" setting in the "Basic Settings" section. If it is set to ".NET CLR Version v2.xxxxx", then the application pool is dependent on .NET Framework 3.5 or below.

You can refer to this official document to learn more about the complete mapping relationship between .NET CLR version and .NET Framework version.
[.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#version-information)

> **CLR 2.0**
>
> .NET Framework 2.0
>
> .NET Framework 3.0
>
> .NET Framework 3.5

> **CLR 4**
>
> .NET Framework 4
>
> .NET Framework 4.5
>
> .NET Framework 4.5.1
>
> .NET Framework 4.5.2
>
> .NET Framework 4.6
>
> .NET Framework 4.6.1
>
> .NET Framework 4.6.2
>
> .NET Framework 4.7
>
> .NET Framework 4.7.1
>
> .NET Framework 4.7.2
>
> .NET Framework 4.8

In addition, you can also refer this: [Determine which .NET implementation and version an app is running on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#determine-which-net-implementation-and-version-an-app-is-running-on)

Comment: i can't believe it is that simple, thank you for the guidance. Great article from Microsoft there too, thank you again.